# without using foreach, how to get all GUID's in List<string> object and send to database method

Tags: c#

May I  how to save all list of guid's in List object, without using foreach and wanted to send all guid's to db method

```
var folderRequestIDs = from GridViewRow msgRow in gvwSearchResult.Rows
                       where ((CheckBox)msgRow.FindControl("chkSNO")).Checked
                       select ((Label)msgRow.FindControl("lblFolderRequestId")).Text;

foreach (string Id in folderRequestIDs)
{
    dataSave(Id, "New")
}
```

Comment: May I know what have you tried?

Comment: please post your code and what u have tried

Comment: Pasted my code, is there a way to send all guid's at once to dataSave method instead of using foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use string.join to join all id in the list with "," or any other symbol you want.

```
var idList = string.Join(",", folderRequestIDs);//you will get a string "id1,id2,id3..."
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, `dataSave` method accepts as an argument only an ID. Right? Its declaration should look something like this

```
void dataSave(int id){
...
}
```

If you want to give a collection as an argument to the specific function, then you would have to either alter it accepting a collection as an argument, or you could [override it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711875%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) using the [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) keyword... This means that the function declaration should look something like this...

```
void dataSave(List<int> idList){
...
}
```

Hope I helped!